# ¿Cómo ordenar resultado de consulta por fecha y hora? MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo esta consulta.

```
select ID from anuncios where COMUNIDAD='Andalucía' AND PROVINCIA='Jaén'
AND (TITULO regexp '^isla|ISLA' OR DESCRIPCION regexp '^isla|ISLA') 
ORDER BY DATE(FECHA) DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Esta consulta me muestra primero los registros mas viejos y me gustaría que me mostrara los mas nuevos primero.

```
EL FORMATO DE LA TABLA ES MAS O MENOS ASI:

ID  COMUNIDAD  PROVINCIA  TITULO    DESCRIPCION      FECHA       HORA
1   Andalucía  Jaén       Rocio     virgen del     2019-03-02  12:15:34
2   Andalucía  Jaén       Pedro     Dia de San     2019-03-04  03:51:01
3   Andalucía  Jaén       Juán      Dia de San     2019-03-07  03:10:00



EL RESULTADO DE LA CONSULTA QUE OBTENGO ES ESTE:
ID
3
2
1
```

Lo que quiero es que también tenga en cuenta la hora al ordenar porque seguro que habrá muchos registros en un mismo día.

Aporto el SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `anuncios` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  `COMUNIDAD` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `PROVINCIA` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `DESCRIPCION` varchar(600) NOT NULL, 
  `FECHA`  date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `HORA` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `anuncios` (`ID`, `COMUNIDAD`, `PROVINCIA`, `TITULO` `DESCRIPCION`, `FECHA`, `HORA`) VALUES
(87, 'Andalucía', 'Jaén', 'Domingo de Ramos', 'domingo 14 de abril de 2019', '2019-03-02', '12:15:34'),
(88, 'Andalucía', 'Jaén', 'domingo 14 de abril de 2019', 'lunes 29 de abril de 2019', '2019-03-02', '12:15:34'),
(89, 'Andalucía', 'Jaén', 'Virgen del Carmen', 'martes 16 de julio de 2019', '2019-03-02', '12:15:34'),
(90, 'Andalucía', 'Jaén', 'martes 16 de julio de 2019', 'sábado 12 de octubre de 2019', '2019-03-02', '12:15:34');


ALTER TABLE `anuncios`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

ALTER TABLE `anuncios`
  MODIFY `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=94;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: ¿Podrías enviarnos la estructura de la tabla en SQL con algún dato para comprobar que funciona? FECHA AND HORA me rechina un poco. Mírate https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve no te vayan a puntuar negativamente la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Ok, por el momento he conseguido ordenarlo por fecha añadiendo esto **DATE(FECHA) DESC**.... pero me falta que tenga en cuenta la hora que la tengo en una columna diferente.... a ver como hago para traer los datos que me pides...

Comment: Por favor, añade el SQL para que tu  ejemplo sea mínimo, completo y verificable. La respuesta es muy fácil, pero tenemos que dejar la pregunta correctamente formulada para que le sirva a más gente. :)

Comment: te refieres a la tabla y el resultado de la consulta verdad? voy a ello... :-)

Comment: El SQL lo obtienes en phpMyAdmin con la opción Exportar. Recuerda votar y marcar la pregunta como respondida

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿por qué guardas `FECHA` y `HORA` en dos columnas distintas, cuando se pueden guardar en una sola columna del tipo [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)?. En ese caso te ahorras una columna, guardando el dato así: `2019-03-02  12:15:34` ... si en algún contexto necesitas sólo la fecha o sólo la hora, la puedes extraer fácilmente con una de las funciones de que dispones en MySQL para ello.

Comment: Cosas de novato!! :-)  Me gusta la forma que tu dices... voy a hacer ese cambio. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ordenar, los campos se separan por comas:

```
SELECT ID from anuncios 
  where COMUNIDAD='Andalucía'
  AND PROVINCIA='Jaén' 
  AND (
      TITULO regexp '^rocio|ROCIO'
      OR DESCRIPCION  regexp '^rocio|ROCIO'
  )
  ORDER BY FECHA DESC, HORA DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias David.... Y también por enseñarme a obtener el SQL... Aunque sinceramente me alegro de no tener que haberlo posteado porque es una autentica locura :-) Saludos!!

Comment: Sí, sí, postéalo para que la pregunta quede correctamente formulada y pueda ayudar a más personas con la misma duda. Eso sí, sólo la estructura de la tabla/s con unos pocos registros de muestra para hacer comprobaciones, no nos los envíes todos... :)

Answer (score 0):

En order by fecha pudes poner ASC o DEC para que sea ascendente o descendente.

```
SELECT ID from anuncios 
  where COMUNIDAD='Andalucía'
  AND PROVINCIA='Jaén' 
  AND (
      TITULO regexp '^rocio|ROCIO'
      OR DESCRIPCION  regexp '^rocio|ROCIO'
  )
  ORDER BY FECHA DESC AND HORA DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias!! Si, es mas o menos así... habría que ponerlo así  **DATE(FECHA) DESC** para funcione bien según acabo comprobar.... me falta que tenga en cuenta la hora tambien que la tengo en otra columna diferente.... ¿Sabes como hacerlo?